ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named ''
I am running ros-humble and have been setting up my console-scripts so that I can run my nodes.
I've used this kind of setup before and have it working for another node, except for some reason I can't get this one to run.
My Code (For Node):
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped


#Create a JointStatePublisher
class LegJointPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('leg_mover') 
        self.get_logger().info('Leg Joint Publisher is online.')
        self.joint_state_pub = self.create_publisher(JointState, 'joint_states', 10) #create publisher to post transforms
        self.timer = self.create_timer(0.1, self.publish_joint_states) #look into

    def publish_joint_states(self):
        joint_state_msg = JointState()
        joint_state_msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
        joint_state_msg.name = ['base_link', 'link_1', 'link_2']  # Replace with the names of your joints
        joint_state_msg.position = [0.0, 1, 0.0]  # Set the positions of your joints here
        joint_state_msg.velocity = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  # Set the velocities of your joints here
        joint_state_msg.effort = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  # Set the efforts of your joints here
        self.joint_state_pub.publish(joint_state_msg)


    #   lower="-1.57"
    #   upper="1.57"
    #   effort="300"
    #   velocity="3" />

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    leg_publisher = LegJointPublisher()
    rclpy.spin(leg_publisher)
    leg_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

My Setup.Py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = 'servo_driver'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['test']),
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='matt',
    maintainer_email='matt@todo.todo',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='Apache-2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            #'servo_pca9685 = scripts.pca9685_test:main',
            'robot_state_pub = scripts.cliffordtransforms:main',
        ],
    },
)

And the error that I get is:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.cliffordtransforms'

I've included a photo of my hierarchy.


The error says module name as scripts.cliffordtransform but your setup has is defined as scripts.cliffordtransforms (additional 's' at the end) can you check for any typos. Then colcon build again and then try to run it

Appreciate the response, that a typo on my end the actual error does say scripts.cliffordtransforms. I've updated it now.

Hi, since the issue is not a simple typo it seems that the scripts folder might not be found as a package. Could you try running the find package in your directory and print it?

In my other packages I had another thing also called scripts could they be conflict between packages, ie this was my node to control joint_states and my other was a teleop related node but both had their executables/nodes under scripts package. I just changed the name and it fixed.
